debian12 ( ソフトウェアRAID1 )をインストールした4TBHDD*2がBIOSのAHCIモードで認識されない
4TBのHDD2本を使用し、debian12をソフトウェアRAID1でインストールしたところ、電源OFF後の初回起動時にBIOSがHDDを認識してくれなくなりました。
BIOSアップデートやHDDの再フォーマットなども試しましたが解決しませんでした。
BIOSのAHCIモードで上記HDDを起動時に認識させるにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。
【現象について】

HDD2本をSATA接続
UEFI > Storage > SATA/NVMe Operation でAHCIモードに変更
この時点では新品のHDD4TBを両方とも認識していました
debian12をソフトウェアRAID1でインストール
再起動
再起動時も問題なくOSが立ち上がりました。
電源OFF
★電源ON

★部分でUEFIがHDDを認識してくれなくなりました。ただ、
①UEFI > storage > STA/NVMe operation を「Raid On」モードにする
②UEFIの再起動を何度か試す（これは電源OFFではなく「EXIT」からのUEFI再表示
どちらかの方法でHDDを認識させることができます。「RaidOn」は継続しますが、①の方は電源OFFにするとHDDを認識しない状態に戻ってしまいます。
※認識しないとは起動デバイスとして表示されないという意味ではなく、そもそもSATA接続の表示の部分がnoneになっており、何も接続されていないことになっているということです。
【マシン詳細】

【ストレージのパーティション情報】
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9
  Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

HDDはGPTでフォーマットしています。
NAME                              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
/dev/sda                            8:0    0  3.6T  0 disk
|-/dev/sda1                         8:1    0  953M  0 part  /boot/efi
`-/dev/sda2                         8:2    0  3.6T  0 part
  `-/dev/md0                        9:0    0  3.6T  0 raid1
    |-/dev/mapper/vg-root 253:0    0  3.6T  0 lvm   /
    `-/dev/mapper/vg-swap 253:1    0 14.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
/dev/sdb                            8:16   0  3.6T  0 disk
|-/dev/sdb1                         8:17   0  953M  0 part  /boot/efi_sub
`-/dev/sdb2                         8:18   0  3.6T  0 part
  `-/dev/md0                        9:0    0  3.6T  0 raid1
    |-/dev/mapper/vg-root 253:0    0  3.6T  0 lvm   /
    `-/dev/mapper/vg-swap 253:1    0 14.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
/dev/sr0 

各HDDにEFIパーティション(sada1,sdb1)を作成、grubをインストールしています。
残りの領域(sada2,sdab2)でRAID1(md0)を作成、md0にボリュームグループを作成し、論理ボリュームでroot(ext4)とswap領域を分割しています。
【試したこと】

BIOSアップデート
1.9.0の最新にアップデートしましたが変わりませんでした。
GPTで再フォーマット
一度認識しなくなったHDDは何度フォーマットしても初回に認識しなくなります。
wipefs -a
GPTフォーマット後、メタデータが残っているのが問題かと思いこちらのコマンドを試しましたが改善しませんでした。
shred -n 1
一度全てを０で埋めると直るかと思いましたが変わりませんでした。
windowsにつなげてのclean all
I/Oデバイスエラーが表示されclean allができません。ただ、debianでは問題なく操作できるためHDDが破損していることは考えづらいです。
SATAケーブルの入れ替え
SATAの接続を入れ替えたりもしましたが効果はありませんでした。
500GBのHDDでインストールしてみる
500GBのHDD2本ではこの現象が起こりませんでした。
別の古いPCにつなぐ
古いPC（2013年購入）のUEFIモードではAHCIモードでもHDDを認識してくれました。

【最終目標】
BIOS > Storage > SATA/NVMe Operation => AHCIモード
で、ソフトウェアRAID1構成のdebian12をインストールしたHDD2本をUEFIに認識させる
【その他補足】
[Raid On」モードでは安定するのですが、ソフトウェアRAIDを組んでいるため、UEFI上で「Raid On」にした場合に設定が競合しないかが不安です。そのため、なんとかAHCIモードで運用したいと考えています。
また、debian12はRAID1構成で問題なく動いており、mdadmでRAID管理もできます。UEFIが初期起動時にHDDを認識してくれないことだけが問題です。
すみません、下記でも同じ質問をしておりますが、解決しなかったためこちらでも投稿させていただきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/imq6tuboqux2nz#reply-900gc7a6r38gdw?_from_e=e_auq_showd
